# Smart Unit Tests: What's the right way to reference Microsoft.Pex.Framework.dll?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

Smart Unit Tests requires a reference to `Microsoft.Pex.Framework.dll`. On my machine this file is located in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Pex\Microsoft.Pex.Framework.dll`.

I don't think that's the right way to reference the file:

1. It's private data of a Visual Studio extension. Developers probably are not supposed to reach into that folder.
2. The path depends on the VS version and OS language.

What's the right way to reference `Microsoft.Pex.Framework.dll` in Visual Studio Smart Unit Tests projects?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For now, referencing by path is the only option.
I will see if we can make it available as a NuGet package.

Comment: Any news about the possibility of a NuGet package?

Comment: We will not be able to take this up for the upcoming updates for Visual Studio 2015. However, we will keep this on our backlog, and look for a suitable opportunity. We are very grateful for the interest in IntelliTest.

Answer (score 1):

Would be great to have this as a NuGet package otherwise the build failes on pure MSBuild buildslaves due to the missing reference..

Answer (score 0):

[IntelliTest in Visual Studio 2015 and greater is the next generation of Pex.](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/project/pex-and-moles-isolation-and-white-box-unit-testing-for-net/?from=http%3A%2F%2Fresearch.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fprojects%2Fpex%2F)

IntelliTest in Visual Studio 2015 is the evolution of Pex. IntelliTest is a feature integrated in Visual Studio Enterprise. IntelliTest works together with Fakes